# Browser controls in Windows universal apps

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app

Any one knows about it ?
Does the WebBrowser control in Windows Universal apps SDK is going to be the old WPF BrowserControl (the activex like control) that uses IE version < 8  only .
Or is any samples to explore the features of universal app Browsercontrol anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

- Check out [WebView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview)
- The msdn page mentions that

  > WebView always uses Internet Explorer 11 in document mode.
- The sample can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Comment: But to support the loading of local files ie files saved in Local system [ example c:\\Myfolder\myfile.html  ] Webview is not the best option . So is any way to use WPF browser control in Universal app

Answer (score 1):

> Over the past several months, we have made numerous improvements to the Microsoft Edge rendering engine (Microsoft EdgeHTML), focusing on interoperability with modern browsers and compliance with new and emerging standards. **In addition to powering Microsoft Edge, EdgeHTML is also available for all Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps via the WebView control.**

Ref: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Building-your-own-Windows-10-Web-Browser